# How do i move a caracter in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, visual-c++

The character is not moving fluidly, is stopping and not moving left or right. I don't know very much about moving a char but I want to learn to use it in my snake project is there any problem with the code?

```
    while(true)
    {
        system("CLS");
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            cout<<map[i]<<endl;
        }
        system("pause>nul");

        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN))
        {
            int y2=y+1;
            if(map[y2][x]==' ')
            {
                map[y][x]=' ';
                y++;
                map[y][x]='@';
            }
        }
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP))
        {
            int y2=y-1;
            if(map[y2][x]==' ')
            {
                map[y][x]=' ';
                y--;
                map[y][x]='@';
            }
        }
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT))
        {
            int x2=x+1;
            if(map[x2][x]==' ')
            {
                map[y][x]=' ';
                x++;
                map[y][x]='@';
            }
        }
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT))
        {
            int x2=x-1;
            if(map[x2][x]==' ')
            {
                map[y][x]=' ';
                x--;
                map[y][x]='@';
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tip: Instead of calling out to commands like `CLS`, just put in the [ANSI escape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) sequence for clearing the screen. Leaning on `system()` here is an extremely bad habit to get into, the cost of those calls can be huge compared to a simple print or get character call.

Comment: As good as I understand, you want your snake to move after key was released. Than just add some variable that will point direction, in which your snake should move, and move to this direction

Comment: What you really need is a proper game loop and input mechanism. This loop runs as fast as you can shell out to those commands (and press keys?). A normal game loop doesn't wait for keys to be 'pressed' per-se, it checks the key state of various keys, like you roughly do here, and moves. Note that updating a game grid this way, by literally manipulating a 2D matrix, is really inefficient. What's better is to have a draw routine that works with layers, like paint the background, then move the cursor to paint the player.

Comment: If you want to make simple DOS-like games, don't forget there's a *ton* of [resources out there](https://github.com/balintkissdev/awesome-dos) to help you through that, with source for many games available for free.

Answer (score 1):

It boils down to how fast and how fluid your game needs to be playable. In slower paced games such as Sudoku, Crossword or Word Search, it's entirely Ok for the screen to be redrawn between moves because the player needs to think about they're next move anyway.

In a game like Snake however, it all comes down to fast movement and quick refresh rate. Both c++ and the windows terminal can achieve this, but re-drawing the entire map will slow you down a lot.

c++ has the char `'\b'` which is equivalent to backspace, and windows has `set str=!str:~0,-1!` for deleting a character in a string. Either will work but they are a bit flashy still.

One thing I notice as well is that you're using [`std::endl` instead of `\n`](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-the-difference-between-endl-and-n-in-cpp#:%7E:text=Both%20endl%20and%20%5Cn%20serve,%2C%20whereas%20%5Cn%20does%20not.). This can cause rough printing because endl flushes the output buffer meaning that it has to re-orient itself before it can print again, and '\n' does not.